Why is promtail: relabel_config: action: drop not dropping?
I have the following promtail configuration:
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    regex: "removeme"
    action: drop
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    regex: "removeme"
    action: keep

Because action is both drop and keep, it should drop everything. But all the logs stay. Why?

Yes, Using action drop and keep together will drop everything. I think you should check if promtail is reloaded, Or you can check the logs and see which ones have been scraped.
